# Ruby enum_for confusion

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find all the subclasses of a certain type called `Command` in Ruby, and I came across the following code which did the trick perfectly, however I don't really understand how it works, mainly the `class << [Subtype]` part. I have tried reading up on this, but I feel there is still some Ruby magic which I am missing. Can someone please explain this to me :-)

```
ObjectSpace.enum_for(:each_object, class << Command; self; end).to_a()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`class << Command; self; end` returns the singleton class of `Command`. This is the class that Command is the only (direct) instance of.

In ruby the singleton class of a subclass of C is a subclass of C's singleton class. So all subclasses of Command have singleton classes that inherit from Command's singleton class.

`ObjectSpace.each_object(C)` iterates over all objects that are instances of the class `C` or one of its subclasses. So by doing `ObjectSpace.each_object(singleton_class_of_command)` you iterate over Command and all its subclasses.

The `enum_for` bit returns an Enumerable that enumerates all the elements that `each_object` iterates over, so you can turn it into an array with `to_a`.

Comment: Brilliant explanation, thanks! So it is essentially the same as this:

    commands = []
    ObjectSpace.each_object(class << Command; self; end) { |c| commands << c } 

it seems really simple now, I should have been able to work that out :)